# Hibernate OneTOMany Mapping Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes called Enquiry.java and EnquiryItem.java

When an enuiry is generated i am saving its items in EnquiryItems.

Below is my mapping files in POJO classes.

Enquiry.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="enquiryId")
@JoinColumn(name = "enq_id",  referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<EnquiryItem> enquiryItems=new ArrayList<EnquiryItem>();
```

EnquiryItem.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="enq_id")
private Enquiry enquiryId;
```

I am unable to locate where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

EDIT: when an enquiry is saved the enquiry_id is saving null in database.

Comment: What type of exception you are getting

Comment: I am unable to figure where I am doing wrong. Please help guys

Comment: @Krushna I am not getting any exception except the enq_id is null in database

Comment: Are you sure your `EnquiryItem`s contain an `Enquiry`? I mean, putting the `EnquiryItem`s in the `Enquiry`’s list is not enough.

Comment: @Etienne Miret yes from the give code you can see. This will enough if we remove the mappedBy attribute and then hibernate will through a update query to update the id.

Comment: That is what I am expecting from the Hibernate. I am telling it to update the id yourself by taking from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you need to set the enquiryId before save it in to database. This required as you have used mappedBy attribute. what you need to do is.

When you are adding EnquiryItem object to the list please set the enquiryId  by calling it's setter method.
EDIT:

like below:

```
EnquiryItem.setEnquiryId(enquiry )
```

EDIT 2:

```
Enquiry enquiry= new Enquiry(bus,prListNo,enquiryNo,user,new java.util.Date(),enquiryItemsList); 
for(EnquiryItem item:enquiryItemsList)
 item.setEnquiryId(enquiry);
```

Comment: At the time of insertion we don't have the id in our hand as the database is going to generate it. So it has to handle it on its own.

Comment: I am not saying to set the database generated id. I am saying to set the Object of type Enquiry to the class EnquiryItem like  EnquiryItem.setEnquiryId(Enquiry  enquiry )

Comment: This is the way how I am generating Enquiry instance ,Enquiry enquiry=new Enquiry(bus,prListNo,enquiryNo,user,new java.util.Date(),enquiryItemsList); where enquiryItemsList is EnquiryItem. Now how can I set it?

Comment: Its not working Krushna. Its throwing StackOverFolw error as it is iterating between Enquiry and EnquiryItem when I am setting EnquiryId

Comment: It should not throw you might be doing some thing wrong , can you put the complete code where you are saving the object.

Comment: Its inserting in database correctly but throwing an exception, SatckOverFlow error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26080/discussion-between-krushna-ch-dash-and-sainath-reddy)